# PHP: Disable @ error control operator

Tags: php

Is there a way to disable the @ error control operator? Currently my script terminates without an error or warning and I enabled display error and error reporting is set to E_ALL. I think there is something that is suppressed by the @ error control operator. I am using a lot of external libraries (composer) and its impossible to search in all of them and maybe I can just disable the @ operator so I identify the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Have also a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203168/php-error-suppression-is-being-ignored) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, there's a library called scream, http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php once installed you can do:

```
ini_set('scream.enabled', true);
```

Or directly in php.ini

```
scream.enabled = On
```